# Python - passing a Boolean to determine who plays first

Tags: python, python-3.4

First time poster here.

I'm relatively new to Python, I've probably been coding roughly 2-3 months in my spare time. In preparation for further study next year.

I've looked everywhere for a solution to this but there doesn't appear to be one. Apologies if that's not the case.

I'm working my way through 'How to think like a computer scientist Python 3". I've become unstuck on the following set of code:

```
def play_once(human_plays_first):
    """
       Must play one round of the game. If the parameter
       is True, the human gets to play first, else the
       computer gets to play first.  When the round ends,
       the return value of the function is one of
       -1 (human wins),  0 (game drawn),   1 (computer wins).
    """
    # This is all dummy scaffolding code right at the moment...
    import random                  # See Modules chapter ...
    rng = random.Random()
    # Pick a random result between -1 and 1.
    result = rng.randrange(-1,2)
    print("Human plays first={0},  winner={1} "
                       .format(human_plays_first, result))
    return result

def play():
    """initiates game and keeps track of score"""
    humanscore = 0
    computerscore = 0
    draws = 0
    total = 0

while True:
    who_plays_first = input("Human plays? Yes or No")
    if who_plays_first == 'Yes':
        who_plays_first = True
    result = play_once(who_plays_first)

    if result == -1:
        humanscore += 1
    if result == 1:
        computerscore += 1
    if result == 0:
        draws += 1

    total = humanscore + computerscore + draws

    PercentageComp = (computerscore / total) *  100
    PercentageComp = round(PercentageComp, 2)
    PercentageHuman = (humanscore / total) *  100
    PercentageHuman = round(PercentageHuman, 2)
    PercentageDraw = (draws / total) *  100
    PercentageDraw = round(PercentageDraw, 2)

    print("Scores are (human, computer and draws):" + str(humanscore) + ","+ str(computerscore) + ","+ str(draws) )
    print("Computers have won:  " + str(PercentageComp) + "%")
    print("Human has one:  " + str(PercentageHuman) + "%")
    print("Draws have occured:  "+ str(PercentageDraw) + "%")

    response = input("Play again? (Yes or No)")
    if response != "yes" and response !="Yes":
        break
print("Goodbye!")
```

play()

Where my issues lies is that it doesn't seem to make any difference whether or not I pass a True to function play_once() or not. The game seems to play the same. I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing here. Nor am I sure how the game should react, it seems that irrespective of whoever goes first all the computer does it randomly select a number to select a winner?

I assume I'm definitely missing here or why else would it even ask who wants to go first?

Thanks

Comment: You pass it in, you print it, and you throw it away. How do you expect it to have any other effect?

Comment: The computer selects a winner randomly because there is nothing else that would influence it. The argument you pass is in is not used for anything except the print function

Comment: Especially the comment `# This is all dummy scaffolding code right at the moment...` indicates that this will actually be implemented later on in the book.